# Ubuntu GPU max graphics clock when focus other window

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Nvidia GTX 1060 3GB. When I surfing my browser (or idle) GPU perf(Performance level) is P8-P10, but if I focus other window (terminal for example) perf is P0(max performance) and GPU-Util is 1-3%. So my question is - **Why when I change focus, perf is P0??**

[Perf level when idle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V47sF.png)

[Perf level when chenged focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWk9W.png)

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @Nmath When I do nothing or focus other window sometimes GPU perf is P0 - max graphics clock and memory frequency